# Load Aegir's site credentials from a php function

Tags: drush, aegir

I'm using Aegir and want to inject some data into a site's vhost.
And I managed to do it thanks to [this post](http://community.aegirproject.org/node/70).

My problem is I can't find an Aegir function to load a site's dabase configurations from [this Aegir functions listing](http://api.aegirproject.org/api/aegir/functions/6.x-2.x) to do it programmatically on each site-verify.

I need to find a function or method that would return a site's data:

- db_name
- db_user
- db_passwd
- etc

I tried `Provision_Config('mysite.com')` but I have a `template argument missing error`.

Does anyone know which function I should use to get the data?
I usually use `drush sql-connect` in ssh, but here I'm not sure it would be a clean way as it should be in a php script.

The goal is to make Drupal work with multi-site / multi-folder (I'm [aware of that post and patch](http://community.aegirproject.org/content/aegir-subfolder-support), but my solution seems to work for me without having to patch anything):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/aegir/platforms/myplatform

  ServerName mysite1.com
  SetEnv db_type  mysql
  SetEnv db_name  mydbname_1
  SetEnv db_user  mydbname_1
  SetEnv db_passwd  *********
  SetEnv db_host  localhost
  SetEnv db_port  9854

  # Credentials from other Aegir's site
  # located in a subfolder /blog.
  <Location /blog>
    SetEnv db_type  mysql
    SetEnv db_name  mydbname_2
    SetEnv db_user  mydbname_2
    SetEnv db_passwd  *********
    SetEnv db_host  localhost
    SetEnv db_port  1258
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I understand what you're after, but if I recall correctly, the vhost files are generated by templates, same way as theme output is. So find the template and you can work out how the data gets there. :)

Comment: Well actually this hook [drush_hook_provision_apache_vhost_config](http://api.aegirproject.org/api/aegir/provision2%21provision.api.php/function/drush_hook_provision_apache_vhost_config/6.x-2.x) let's me alter the output of the vhost file which would let me add the <Location /blog> data as needed.

My problem is trying to use the [Provision_Config_Apache_Site](http://api.aegirproject.org/api/aegir/provision2%21http%21Provision%21Config%21Apache%21Site.php/class/Provision_Config_Apache_Site/6.x-2.x) class to get the other site db information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Installing sites in sub-directories is supported in Aegir 2+ without any such hacking. Just enable the "Site subdirectories" feature, under the 'experimental' group at admin/hosting/features.

That said, to answer your question, DB credentials are available via drush_get_context('site').

Answer (score 1):

> I usually use drush sql-connect in ssh, but here I'm not sure it would
>   be a clean way as it should be in a php script.

If I understand correctly, you are writing a custom PHP script that needs to connect to the database of a Drupal site managed by Aegir?

If yes, you can use:

```
$ drush php-script your-script.php
```

This bootstraps Drupal (and connects the database) and will call your script as if you had run `$ php your-script.php` on the command line.